# Another form of time display in Postgres table vs Grafana

Tags: postgresql, time, grafana

I have a problem with display time value from Postgres DB in Grafana table.

In Postgres I have a column  time_1 (time without time zone) with value
**00:00:28.973**

but on Grafana the same value is display like:

**1753-08-30 00:08:10**

The query is very simple only

```
SELECT
...
times.best_time.time_1 AS "Time_1",
...
FROM
...
```

Time setting in Grafana:
Coordinated Universal Time UTC, GMT

Any suggestion how to display in exactly the same way like in Postgres?
I need this value for display time lap

Comment: You could try to retrieve it as a string: `to_char(time_1, 'hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for